# How to (truly) become different user over ssh

Tags: debian, ssh, users

I want to change my username in linux, e.g. `sudo usermod -l new old`, but I am getting an error

> `usermod: user old is currently used by process 4139`

That is obvious, since I am logged over ssh

> `old    4139  0.0  0.2  17032  5140 ?        S    18:31   0:00 sshd: old@pts/0`

Even if I `su root`, I will just start new shell as different user. For security reasons, I can't login over the ssh as different user. How can I overcome this issue.

One option would be to either temporarily lower the security (change sshd config) or create temporary user, setup ssh key, add him to sudoers, login with that different user and then clean everything up. This seams like very tedious work. Is there an easier way of doing this?

Comment: Can't you just create init script (init.d) that change the user after restart? Be cautious tho, you might even can't log in via ssh if something goes wrong.

Comment: @fawildchild That seems even more dangerous (in a sense that if it goes wrong, I am screwed) than the fuss with creating temporary user

Comment: That's not possible via usermod -- it has no option to override that check. Also, not only your shell, but also its parent (the sshd process which handles the connection) is running as the user you logged in as, so that won't work even if you `exec su ...` from your shell. The only way I can think of is to use `vipw` and `vipw -s`, though the potential to break your system or lock yourself out is great.

Comment: If you can't get console & root access, I would recommend setting up a second username BEFORE attempting to change the first.  For instance, if usermod doesn't change sudoers, and you forget to, you could be locked out of root.

Answer (score 1):

Try and see it works with `exec su root`. That should replace the shell with `su`, and might not have any processes running under `old` running.

If that doesn't work, just arrange to log in as root, and do it that way. Or just edit the user database manually and take the possible confusion it might cause (Honestly, I doubt there's actually much effect, but in any case, keep a privileged session open in the meanwhile anyway.) In any case, `usermod` doesn't change the home directory, so you'll have to do that separately.

I fail to see the relevant difference in "lowering the security" between logging directly in as root, and creating a new user to sudo to root with.

Comment: Regarding the lowering the security, I can't login via root over ssh, so I would have to enable that (which lowers security). Also `exec su root` didn't completely work for me (ssh process of previous user was still running). I will do the fuss with another user.